# how can add custom JTable code to GUI Builder Nebeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

how can add custom Jtable to GUI Builder netbeans form

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String data[][] = {{"Vinod","MCA","Computer"},
                      {"Deepak","PGDCA","History"},
                      {"Ranjan","M.SC.","Biology"},
                      {"Radha","BCA","Computer"}};
    String col[] = {"Name","Course","Subject"};    
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
    table = new JTable(model);
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    Object obj1 = GetData(table, 2, 2);
    System.out.println("Cell value of 3 column and 3 row :" + obj1);
    Object obj2 = GetData(table, 2, 1);
    System.out.println("Cell value of 2 column and 3 row :" + obj2);
    panel.add(pane);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500,150);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public Object GetData(JTable table, int row_index, int col_index){
    return table.getModel().getValueAt(row_index, col_index);
  }  
}
```

Comment: now, what is the question? Do you want to be able to drag and drop a custom component to the GUI designer?

Comment: no I want this code can be embed in Gui builder form if i not use the JTable(drag and drop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Now that you have provided some details, Here is the answer for you.
There are multiple ways to do this.

**one: using GUI**

- Once you place the JTable component on the GUI designer,
- Right-click on the table cells( white area of the JTable )
- From popup menu, choose "Table Contents.." - this shows a customizer dialog.
- Choose "Custom code" in "Table Model" tab.
- Place the following code to the text box:

  ```
  new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel( new Object [][] {
      {"Vinod","MCA","Computer"},
      {"Deepak","PGDCA","History"},                
      {"Ranjan","M.SC.","Biology"},
      {"Radha","BCA","Computer"}},
      new String [] {"Name","Course","Subject"})
  ```
- Save your changes.
  (Now notice that the jTable may not display properly on your designer, but that is OK)

**two: using code fragments**

- Once you place the JTable component on the GUI designer,
- Right-click on the table cells( white area of the JTable )
- From popup menu, choose properties - this shows property settings
- On the properties dialog, switch to code from top buttons ( properties, binding,events,code)
- on the grid, click on the edit button(marked '...') against "After All-set Code" option.
- This will allow you to edit some code after table is all set. Place the following code in to that editor (assuming your table's name is jTable1)

  ```
     jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {
                {"Vinod","MCA","Computer"},
                {"Deepak","PGDCA","History"},
                {"Ranjan","M.SC.","Biology"},
                {"Radha","BCA","Computer"}
      },
      new String [] {
          "Name","Course","Subject"
      }));
      jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(java.awt.Color.yellow);
  ```

note: this covers the color change as well, so  better control here.

- Save your changes